# spring boot thymeleaf multiple select data binding mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am struggling with data binding to user and group. I am using mongodb.

**User** model

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String firstName;
   private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
   //getters and setters
}
```

And **Group** model

```
@Document(collection = "groups")
public class Group {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
}
```

User **add** method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(User user, Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("groupList",mongoOperations.findAll(Group.class));
   return "users/add";
}
```

And thymeleaf html

```
<form th:object="${user}" method="post">
<select multiple class="form-control" th:field="${user.groups}" >
                            <option th:each="grp : ${groupList}"
                                    th:text="${grp.name}"
                                    th:value="${grp.id}" />
                        </select>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne - its not mapping, I get null value for user groups.